# Обновление отдельных элементов

Tags: php, ajax

У меня есть **ссылка**, при нажатии которой выполняется php код и файла *file.php*, все это реализовано на ajax, без перезагрузки страницы.
Вверху страницы у меня есть переменная *$per* , она выводит значения из базы.
После выполнения кода из файла *file.php* значение переменной *$per* изменяется, но чтоб новое значение увидеть, необходимо перезагрузить страницу.
Как сделать чтобы значение переменной изменялось после нажатия **ссылки**.
Код **ссылки**:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#link").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "start.php",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(response){
                    $("#content").html(response);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<a href="#" id="link" onclick="return false"><img src="/style/img/start.png" alt="" /></a>
```

Содержимое файла `start.php`:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET time = '".rand(0, 100)."' WHERE id = '$user[id]' LIMIT 1");
echo 'Принято';
```

Comment: Так а в чем проблема-то? Отдавайте новую разметку в файле `start.php` и все.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev в файле `start.php` у меня в нем уже есть новая разметка, которая выводится в `index.php` после нажатия кнопки, она выводится в блоке `id="content"` . мне же нужно чтоб еще в одном блоке обновлялось значение

Comment: А может быть имеет смысл отразить все это **в вопросе** чтобы не нужно было играть в "угадайку"? И привести код `start.php` заодно.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev код `start.php` : *mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `time` = '".rand(0, 100)."' WHERE `id` = '$user[id]' LIMIT 1");
echo 'Принято';*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В файле `start.php` можно отдавать *JSON* со всеми блоками, которые нужно обновить:

```
// .... код генерации блоков
$blocks = array(
    'header' => 'Новый контент для блока #header',
    'content' => 'Новый контент для блока #content',
);

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo(json_encode($blocks));
```

А в JavaScript коде обновлять все необходимые блоки:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#link").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "start.php",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response){
                $("#header").html(response.header);
                $("#content").html(response.content);
            }
        });
    });
});
```